# Fake content in serialized array

Tags: arduino, c++

I have network structures and a container structure (nvs) that holds the number of networks and a pointer chain for each network. I would like to serialize this container and then store it in Non Volatile Storage under one key.
Adding an item works fine but by serialization I get some stupid result az the serialize.memcpy() and can't figure out why.
The stored structure look like

[image]

Serialized nvs_p should looks like

[image]

as a char array to be able to store as a value in NVS.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

typedef struct network {
    char SSID[50];
    char PASS[50];

    network(const char* s, const char * p) {
      memset(SSID, 0, 50);
      memset(PASS, 0, 50);
      strcpy(PASS, p);
      strcpy(SSID, s);
    }
  } network_t, *network_p;

typedef struct nvs {
    network_p* networks;
    uint8_t items;
} nvs_t, *nvs_p;

uint8_t *serialize(const nvs_p nw) {
  uint8_t networksCount = nw->items;
  unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)calloc(1, sizeof(unsigned char) + networksCount * sizeof(network_t));
  buffer[0] = networksCount;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < networksCount; i++ )
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(uint8_t) + i * sizeof(network_t), nw->networks[i], sizeof(network_t));
  return buffer;
}

nvs_p deserialize(const unsigned char *buff) {
  nvs_p ret = (nvs_p)malloc(sizeof(nvs_t));
  memcpy(&(ret->items), &(buff[0]), sizeof(uint8_t));
  ret->networks = (network_p*)malloc(ret->items * sizeof(network_p));
  for(int i=0, offset = sizeof(network_t);i<ret->items;i++, offset += sizeof(network_t)) {
    ret->networks[i] = (network_p)malloc(sizeof(network_t));
    memcpy(&(ret->networks[i]), buff + i * sizeof(network_t), sizeof(network_t));
  }
  return ret;
}

nvs_p add(nvs_p all, network_p net) {
  if(all==NULL)
    all = (nvs_p)calloc(1, sizeof(nvs_t));
  
  all->networks = (network_p*)realloc(all->networks, (all->items+1) * sizeof(network_p));
  all->networks[all->items] = (network_p)malloc(sizeof(network_t));
  memcpy(all->networks[all->items], net, sizeof(network_t));
  all->items++;
  return all;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();

  nvs_p all;
  network_t net = network_t("alma","körte");
  all = add(all, &net);
  strcpy(net.SSID,"szilva");
  strcpy(net.PASS,"narancs");
  all = add(all, &net);
  uint8_t *str = serialize(all);
  nvs_p sec = deserialize(str);
}

void loop() {}
```

**Feed:**

Items=2

### SSID:alma
PWD:körte

### SSID:szilva
PWD:narancs

**serializing output:**

Items=2

D9 DA DB DC DD DE DF E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FB FC FD FE FF 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A

0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C

3D 3E 3F 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E

6F 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F A0

Output dump should begin with
41 6C 6D 61 00...(Alma)
4B F6 72 74 65 00...(Körte)
53 7A 69 6C 76 61 00...(Szilva)
4E 61 72 61 6E 63 73 00...(Naramcs)

Comment: The issue lies in how you're handling pointers to network_p during serialization and deserialization. When you serialize the network structures, you need to copy the data they point to, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: What does "some stupid result" mean? Give us a specific example of what input you're feeding in, what output you expect, and what output you actually get.

Comment: It looks to me as though you're declaring nvs_t.networks as a pointer to a pointer to a network_t, instead of just a pointer to a network_t.

Answer (score 0):

fixed serialize():

```
char *serialize(const nvs_p nw, char *buffer) {
    uint8_t networksCount = nw->items;
    buffer = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(unsigned char) + networksCount * sizeof(network_t));
    memcpy(buffer, &networksCount, sizeof(uint8_t));
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < networksCount; i++)
        memcpy(buffer + sizeof(uint8_t) + i * sizeof(network_t), nw->networks[i], sizeof(network_t));
    return buffer;
}
```

and deserialize():

```
nvs_p deserialize(const char *buff) {
  nvs_p ret = (nvs_p)calloc(1, sizeof(nvs_t));
  memcpy(&ret->items, buff, sizeof(uint8_t));
  buff += sizeof(uint8_t);
  ret->networks = (network_p*)calloc(ret->items, sizeof(network_p));
  for (int i = 0; i < ret->items; i++) {
      ret->networks[i] = (network_p)calloc(1, sizeof(network_t));
      memcpy(ret->networks[i], buff + i * sizeof(network_t), sizeof(network_t));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

all things going as I expected